# Cannot make my python web scraping script to work with multiprocessing

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

I read my urls from a csv and I want at the end to export the results in a new csv. There are about 60 URLs I use the following

```
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
import requests 
from time import sleep
from multiprocessing import Pool

contents = []

with open('websupplies2.csv') as csvf:
 reader = csv.reader(csvf, delimiter=";")
 for row in reader:
    contents.append(row) # Add each url to list contents

 price_text='-'
 availability_text='-'

def parse(contents):
  info = []
  with open('output_websupplies.csv', mode='w') as f:
  f_writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=';', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
  f_writer.writerow(['SKU','Price','Availability'])

  for row in contents:  # Parse through each url in the list.
  sleep(3)
  page = requests.get(row[1]).content
  soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")

  price = soup.find('div', attrs={'class':'product-price'})
  if price is not None:
   price_text = price.text.strip()
   print(price_text)
  else:
   price_text = "0,00"
   print(price_text)

  availability = soup.find('div', attrs={'class':'available-text'})
  if availability is not None:
   availability_text = availability.text.strip()
   print(availability_text)
  else:
   availability_text = "Μη Διαθέσιμο"
   print(availability_text)

  info.append(row[0])
  info.append(price_text)
  info.append(availability_text)

return ';'.join(info)     

if __name__ == "__main__":
 with Pool(10) as p:
 records = p.map(parse, contents)

if len(records) > 0:
 with open('output_websupplies.csv', 'a+') as f:
    f.write('\n'.join(records))
```

But I get error messages like Name Error records is not defined. What should I change in order the script to  work?

Answer (score 1):

Start by double-checking your indentation.  It looks inconsistent in what you've pasted here, and if your `if len(records) > 0:` line really *isn't* indented, you'll certainly get a NameError there.

In order for a statement to be inside a block, it must have an indent equal to the other statements in the block, and greater than the line which opens the block.  In other words, everything inside an `if` statement should line up.  For example:

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    with Pool(10) as p:
        records = p.map(parse, contents)

        if len(records) > 0:
            with open('output_websupplies.csv', 'a+') as f:
                f.write('\n'.join(records))
```

Comment: My first errors come on info.append(row[0])
    info.append(price_text)
    info.append(availability_text)

Comment: @Evridiki — I've added an example to my answer.

Comment: The last part  logic is correct? I dont forget something ?

Comment: @Evridiki — I'm not familiar with the `Pool` API, but the rest of that block looks fine, aside from the indentation.

Comment: I get a Invalid URL 'd': No schema supplied. Perhaps you meant http://d? error on info.append(availability_text) the indentation on visual studio looks ok it was running before I add pool API